# Comparing two columns to find minimum value with only one row populated in column 1

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet with the following columns:

[image: spreadsheet — input]

I want to get minimum value of "FCITC" corresponding to the "From" number in the sheet. As you can see, the "From" is listed only once and then there are multiple values in "FCITC" column.

I want my output to show the following based on the table above:

[image: expected results]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Use two helper columns.  Put this in an empty column(I used Column D2)

```
=IF(A2<>"",A2,D1)
```

Copy over on column and down

[image]

Then create a pivot table from those three columns:

1. put From and To in the Rows
2. Put FCITC in the Values and change it to Min
3. IN the design tab, click the Report Layout and choose Tabular Form
4. Under Subtotals, turn them off
5. Under Grand totals, turn them off

[image]